# While running the PS tools in CMD i get the trust relationship error

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line

I was trying to setup a set of computers to control them through LAN network using PS tools. All my computers are **Windows 7 Professional 32bit**. I installed the PS tools. I also added the **LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy** DWORD with value **1** in the location *HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System* in all the slave computers. Then I tried to run a simple PSTool command `psshutdown \\10.5.168.1 -r` to perform a simple restart operation to check the working of the PSTools and I get the error

**Couldn't access 10.5.168.1**

**The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed**

If there is any way to solve this error, it would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the remote machines can actually log in to the domain. Try to restart one of them then log in as a domain user. Chances are, you wouldn't be able to log in and get the "trust relationship" error. If that's the case, log in as a local administrator account and rejoin the domain by leaving the domain, restart, then join the domain again.